# How to make a text file read-only in a non-rooted device?

Tags: file-system, file-management, file-permissions, android-10, es-file-explorer

I wanted to make a file read-only (440)in internal storage but it shows "failed",as it seemingly requires root permission but I can't unlock bootloader as of now so is there any means we can do the above task?

Comment: Not the exact solution but with root access you can set immutable flag (`chattr +i`) on file on underlying real filesystem (in `/data/media/`).

Comment: How to get root access, is it possible with unrooted phone?